# Test instrumentation process crashed while running espresso tests

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a simple espresso test, which requires to open my app switch tabs and click on a RecyclerView's row, which opens a WebView. The WebView opens properly, with the whole content, but then it throws this error.

**Logcat:**

> 2019-08-07 15:35:50.409 18902-18902/com.myProject.ui E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(89)] stat /data/user/0/com.myProject.ui/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
>   2019-08-07 15:35:50.409 18902-18902/com.myProject.ui E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.myProject.ui/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions, in order for my test to run successfully, i had to close the webView before finishing the tests. So i get no longer this error, neither "test instrumentation process crashed". I hope this answer might help others.

Answer (score 3):

In my scenario it occurs only First time lunch the WebView.

This error is because of Android 9 and chrome 76.0.3809.89. Lower version of Android Is working fine I have tested in Android 5.1.1

In android WebView uses the chrome as browser.

Hope next version of chrome will fix this error.

Comment: same for me happens only for the first time and the app crashed on Android 9.
I have a hybrid app build in Ionic. Lower versions working fine.
Any link to the known issue?

Comment: Downgraded chrome version and it worked fine..thanks for sharing the information. Looking forward to the official documentation.