# Ionic App breaking on Android 9 after 1st install

Tags: cordova, ionic3, android-9.0-pie

I have an app built using IONIC3 and cordova below are the configurations.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/Users/vasnagpa/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.2.2, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (31 plugins total)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v8.2.0 (/Users/vasnagpa/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 5.3.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Recently on Android 9 after installing the app for the first time if I try to open the app it breaks. But if I kill the app and launch again it works fine.
I checked the app logs by connecting to browser it fails and gives CORS error for server API's.
But I do not think the issue is related to CORS as it works after killing the app. I suspect maybe a cordova plugin is breaking.
I commented out a few plugins to make it work but no results.

Please help and suggestions for the fix or debugging.

Comment: did you watch the logcat for potential errors?

Comment: Yes I did it gives a bunch of feedback not sure what is the exact issue.

Comment: Errors would be in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have the answer. Saw a similar thread
[Test instrumentation process crashed while running espresso tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395365/test-instrumentation-process-crashed-while-running-espresso-tests)

Downgraded my chrome version and it worked fine. Still looking for some official documentation on the issue or maybe a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Official bug ticket:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107

Hope it helps someone.